# npm install: npm can't find a package.json file in current directory

Tags: npm, phoenix-framework

Recently, when I've tried to run `npm install` in a phoenix app, I've gotten this error:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/sam/Projects/xxxx/xxxx/file:deps/phoenix/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/sam/Projects/xxxx/xxxx/file:deps/phoenix/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
```

However, when I look in deps/phoenix, there definitely a package.json file.

This is the main application's package.json:

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "brunch": "2.10.9",
    "clean-css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "sass-brunch": "2.10.4",
    "elm-brunch": "^0.9.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~2.0.1"
  }
}
```

and deps/phoenix/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "phoenix",
  "version": "1.2.1",
  "description": "The official JavaScript client for the Phoenix web framework.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "./priv/static/phoenix.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix.git"
  },
  "author": "Chris McCord <chris@chrismccord.com> (http://www.phoenixframework.org)",
  "devDependencies": {
    "brunch": "~2.6.5",
    "mocha": "~2.4.4",
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~2.0.1"
  },
  "files": ["README.md", "LICENSE.md", "package.json", "priv/static/phoenix.js"],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha ./web/test/**/*.js --compilers js:babel-register"
  }
}
```

Comment: check for permissions. Try sudo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still got the error.

Comment: never blindly resort to using sudo to help ~fix~ npm issues ... first understand where your node packages live by issuing :  echo $NODE_PATH   ... if your id can write into that dir then no sudo is needed

Comment: in your /Users/sam/Projects/xxxx/xxxx/packages.json ... instead of "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix"  ... try ... "phoenix": "1.2.1"    ... if this works then do similar for package phoenix_html if it then fails  ... assure you are cd into /Users/sam/Projects/xxxx/xxxx when you issue ... npm install

Comment: I still had the error